# Creating new tag in python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to create new tags in an HTML file and add information to them. I wrote the following python code, following the example given in the beautifulsoup documentation, but it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("content.htm") as insert:
    content = BeautifulSoup(insert, "html.parser")

    #Find the tag you wish to append to.
    original_tag = content.find("body")

    #Create & append new tags.
    new_tag = content.new_tag("button", class="accordion")
    original_tag.append(new_tag)

    new_tag = content.new_tag("div", class="panel")
    original_tag.append(new_tag)

    new_tag = content.new_tag("p")
    original_tag.append(new_tag)

print(content)
```

I wished to add the abovementioned 3 new tags between the:

```
<body></body>
```

part of the HTML document. It doesn't work. Where am I going wrong? The above classes, "accordion" and "panel" are added to the tags and used by another javascript program.

Comment: `.another_tag`, `.final_tag`?  You can't do that. And `class` is a reserved name, use `class_` instead.

Comment: I changed the code to the above, it still doesn't work. Can you give a code example?

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine, if you replace `class` with `class_`

Comment: That defeats the purpose, both "accordion" and "panel" classes will then be used by another javascript. Is there another way to add classes to tags?

Comment: You're right the new tags have a `class_` attribute, sorry i missed that. But you could add a 'class' attribute after you've created the tag. For example, create the tag: `new_tag = content.new_tag("div")` and add the class: `new_tag["class"] = "panel"`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked!